# Construct an example where x(t, x_0) is bounded but lim→+∞ x(t, x_0) does not exist.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples

Suppose we are given an IVP $x = f(x), x(0) = x_0 $,  x ∈ R^n for which we know that the unique solution x(t, x_0) exists globally in time. Construct an example where x(t, x_0) is bounded but lim→+∞ x(t, x_0) does not exist.
 Show however that  $$\int_{0}^{\infty} ||f(x(s,x_0))||ds$$ < ∞,
then necessarily lim→+∞ x(t,x_0) exists.

I could not figure out such examples. Can anyone has some idea about this?

Comment: Take $f(x)=x$, then $x_0 \cos(t)$ solves the problem (any function with $x(0)=x_0$ will solve the problem) and is bounded. Also $\lim_{t \to \infty} x_0 \cos(t)$ does not exist.

Comment: For the second part, note that $f(x(s,x_0))=x(s,x_0)$ for any solution of the problem. If $x(s,x_0)$ is continuous and $\int_0^\infty ||x(s,x_0)|| ds <\infty$ then a simple argument shows you that $\lim_{t\to \infty} ||x(t,x_0)|| = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully your differential equation is $\dot x=f(x)$.

Then consider the equation of circular motion with $f(x)=Jx$, $J^2=-I$ or more concrete, $f((x_1,x_2))=(-x_2,x_2)$.

The finiteness condition tells you that the curve length of $x$ in the state space,
$$
\int_0^\infty \|\dot x(t)\|\,dt
$$
is finite, and thus this curve has an end point.

Another way to see this is that $x(t_n)$ in any time series $t_n\to\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence since
$$
\|x(t_n)-x(t_m)\|\le \int_{\min(t_m,t_n)}^\infty\|\dot x(t)\|\,dt
$$
and 
$$
\int_T^\infty\|\dot x(t)\|\,dt\xrightarrow[\ T\to\infty\ ]{}0
$$